# Plugin settings per site/locale

Tags: plugin-development, settings, craft3

I'm trying to make a plugin in Craft 3 but want it to be possible to set different settings for each separate site or locale. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit

OP updated the question to specify Craft *3*, so this is no longer relevant.

---

You can define a separate value for each locale, as described in [the localisation documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/localization-guide#step-4-define-your-site-uRLs):

```
<?php

return [
    'flagName' => [
        'de' => 'Bundesflagge',
        'fr' => 'Tricolore',
    ],
];
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work, I'm trying to do this in Craft 3 though, are you sure it's the same?

Comment: Ah, I see you updated the question. I'm not sure about Craft 3, but I suspect it's different.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the above only ever applied to the `siteUrl` and wasn't generalized to work for any setting