# Plugin settings per site / locale (Craft 3)

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

This is a followup question to [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/20381/plugin-settings-per-site-locale/20382) which asked about the possibility of per-site plugin config for Craft 3.

I'm a plugin author and have had a feature request for allowing my plugin to have different settings based on the current site. Looking at the above question, it sounds like this used to be possible in Craft 2:

```
<?php

return [
    'flagName' => [
        'de' => 'Bundesflagge',
        'fr' => 'Tricolore',
    ],
];
```

This doesn't work in Craft 3, alas (throws an error). I could write something into my plugin's admin area to loop through known sites and output config per-site but this seems like something Craft should be able to do out-of-the-box (especially given the above method used to be valid). Does anyone know if there's a good way to do this in Craft 3?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the above only ever applied to the `siteUrl` and wasn't generalized to work for any setting for Craft 2.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There is no native support for this](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/2028), you can follow my approach and create a custom table for it to store the settings for each site

Another way is to return a different array depending on the current site in your config file

```
if(Craft::$app->getSites()->getCurrentSite()->handle === X){
    return ['flagName' => 'Tricolore'];
} else {
    return ['flagName' => 'Bundesflagge'];
}
```

or

```
$array = [
    'de' => [
        'flagName' => 'Bundesflagge'
    ],
    'fr' => [
        'flagName' => 'Tricolore'
    ]
];

return $array[Craft::$app->getSites()->getCurrentSite()->handle];
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need site-specific config for the plugin in the control-panel, you have to check for the site-param

```
<?php
$handle = Craft::$app->request->isCpRequest ?  Craft::$app->request->getParam('site') : Craft::$app->getSites()->getCurrentSite()->handle;
$array = [
  'de' => [
    ...
   ],
  'en' => [
    ...
  ]
];
return $array[$handle];
?>
```

getCurrentSite() always returns the primary site for cp.

Answer (score 1):

These solutions work great, but I found an alternative, which suited my use-case a bit better.

If you create a Global (e.g. handle `cookieNotice`) in CMS with **translatable** fields (e.g. text fields with handles `cookieMessage`, `cookieLearnMoreText`, ..), you can add them to your custom plugin config as follows;

```
<?php
    $global = Craft::$app->globals->getSetByHandle('cookieNotice');
    return [
        'message' => $global->cookieMessage,
        'learn' => $global->cookieLearnMoreText,
        'learn_more_link' => $global->cookieLearnMoreLink,
        'dismiss' => $global->cookieButtonText
    ];
```

This automatically returns the **translated** value for your site, and let you change the values from CMS.

*Note: in my case, the fields were basic text fields, you may have to customise `$global->cookieMessage` for different field types.*